# haproxy - cannot bind socket error - ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, haproxy

I followed the instructions here https://kifarunix.com/install-and-setup-haproxy-on-ubuntu-20-04/ & have almost set up HTTPS. The function `beam.smp` which is specific to couchdb was bound to 5984 & hence not allowing haproxy to start.

Error log from terminal:

```
Oct 04 08:11:58 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Oct 04 08:11:58 AgentDost systemd[1]: Stopped HAProxy Load Balancer.
Oct 04 08:11:58 AgentDost systemd[1]: Starting HAProxy Load Balancer...
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost haproxy[31476]: [ALERT] 276/081158 (31476) : Starting frontend couch.tezi.app: cannot bind socket [174.138.120.68:5984]
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost haproxy[31476]: Proxy webapps started.
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost haproxy[31476]: Proxy webapps started.
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost haproxy[31476]: [ALERT] 276/081158 (31476) : Starting proxy stats: cannot bind socket [174.138.120.68:5984]
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
```

So I stopped the service to be able to bind the haproxy service to the port. Now `beam.smp` is not bound to the port but still haproxy is not able to takeover. What could be the reason here?

```
Oct 04 08:11:58 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Oct 04 08:11:58 AgentDost systemd[1]: Stopped HAProxy Load Balancer.
Oct 04 08:11:58 AgentDost systemd[1]: Starting HAProxy Load Balancer...
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost haproxy[31476]: [ALERT] 276/081158 (31476) : Starting frontend couch.tezi.app: cannot bind socket [174.138.120.68:5984]
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost haproxy[31476]: Proxy webapps started.
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost haproxy[31476]: Proxy webapps started.
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost haproxy[31476]: [ALERT] 276/081158 (31476) : Starting proxy stats: cannot bind socket [174.138.120.68:5984]
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost systemd[1]: Stopped HAProxy Load Balancer.
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 04 08:11:59 AgentDost systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
root@AgentDost:~# sudo ss -4 -tlnp | grep 80
LISTEN    0         511                0.0.0.0:80               0.0.0.0:*        users:(("nginx",pid=751,fd=6),("nginx",pid=750,fd=6))                          
root@AgentDost:~# ss -4 -tlnp | grep 5984
```

I tried changing the frontend to port 6984 but even that doesn't help.

Error log from terminal:

```
Oct 04 08:21:26 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Oct 04 08:21:26 AgentDost systemd[1]: Stopped HAProxy Load Balancer.
Oct 04 08:21:26 AgentDost systemd[1]: Starting HAProxy Load Balancer...
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost haproxy[31747]: [ALERT] 276/082126 (31747) : Starting frontend couch.tezi.app: cannot bind socket [174.138.120.68:6984]
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost haproxy[31747]: Proxy webapps started.
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost haproxy[31747]: Proxy webapps started.
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost haproxy[31747]: [ALERT] 276/082126 (31747) : Starting proxy stats: cannot bind socket [174.138.120.68:5984]
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost systemd[1]: Stopped HAProxy Load Balancer.
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 04 08:21:27 AgentDost systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
root@AgentDost:~# ss -4 -tlnp | grep 6984
root@AgentDost:~# ss -4 -tlnp | grep 5984
LISTEN    0         128                0.0.0.0:5984             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("beam.smp",pid=31658,fd=16))
```

Comment: This is a configuration problem not a programming problem, ask the question on ServerFault

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The problem was with config file of haproxy. Its resolved now but SO doesn't let me mark it as solved :|